# Regarding Android NDK Removal

Tags: android, windows, xamarin, android-ndk, uninstallation

I have so many android ndks and sdks installed in my laptop and takes up space.

Because I use Android Studio I think I shouldn't uninstall the sdk but there are so many ndks.

Also, that I use Xamarin, I need one package of ndks so I thought which one should I uninstall.
And I can't see them in Programs and Features.

I'm using Windows, by the way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> I can't see them in Programs and Features.

The NDKs aren't "installed" like typical Windows programs. They are just extracted zip files. To remove them you just delete them from your file system.

To remove any downloaded with Android Studio, they can be removed via the SDK Manager in Android Studio. For things installed with other tools, they might have a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one installation of Android SDK/NDK and delete the rest. You can manually set the SDK and Path in the Visual Studio and Android Studio to use

Comment: FYI, this does assume that all the tools you use support the NDK you choose. Idk what versions of the NDK Xamarin supports, but Android Studio should support up through r13 beta 2.